# Itemize spacing in tabularx environment

Tags: spacing, itemize, tabularx

I'm trying to use `itemize` inside a `tabularx` environment, but I have a problem when I mention the end of the line. It seems that using `\\` end the line after the end of `itemize`, resulting in a supplementary vertical spacing that I would like to remove.

Any hint?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sujet de thèse}
        \begin{center}
            \textit{Sujet N$^\circ$221 : Formation et dynamique des champs de dunes longitudinales.}
        \end{center}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l !{\color{blue}\vline width 3pt} X}
            Contexte &  \scriptsize{Classification des dunes selon leur mécanisme de croissance, leur orientation et leur forme. 
            Bonne compréhension :
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt, label=\textbullet]
                \item du mécanisme de croissance lié à une disponibilité en sédiment grande.
                \item de la croissance sous un vent unidirectionnel.
            \end{itemize}} \\
            Objectifs & \scriptsize{Etude de l'orientation longitudinale :
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt, label=\textbullet, parsep=0pt ]
                \setlength\itemsep{0cm}
                \item Développement d'un formalisme sous des vents multidirectionnels.
                \item Etude des dunes longitudinales dans le cas d'une faible disponibilité en sédiment. (Fingering mode)
                \item Inversion: données topographiques $\longrightarrow$ Données de vents $\rightarrow$ paléo-climats. 
            \end{itemize}} \\
            Outils & \scriptsize{Modèle numérique (Rescal), Données expérimentales, Théorie.} \\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{frame}
```

[image]

And yes, dunno if it's important but everything is inside beamer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `\\`. Simply, at the end of a list environment, a vertical spacing is added(`\baselineskip+\topsep`). A solution consists in adding a negative vertical spacing, with the `after=` key of `enumitem`, which lets you add some code at the end of the environment.

I took the opportunity to simplify the code, and propose another layout for the itemize environment, that I think better in a table cell. You can see the result of the `wide=0pt` option in the first row.

As I suppose you load the `frenchb` module of `babel`, note there is a `\No` command for `N°`, and that, in French typography,  capital letters also take an accent.

If you have many tables with such itemize environments, it might be shorter to define a new `tabitemize` environment, with the specific parameters you have, instead of repeating the options each time.

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx, enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sujet de thèse}
        \begin{center}
            \textit{Sujet \No221 : Formation et dynamique des champs de dunes longitudinales.}
        \end{center}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l !{\color{blue}\vline width 3pt} >{\scriptsize}X}
            Contexte & Classification des dunes selon leur mécanisme de croissance, leur orientation et leur forme.
            Bonne compréhension :
            \begin{itemize}[wide = 0pt, leftmargin =*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt, label=\textbullet, after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip}]
                \item du mécanisme de croissance lié à une disponibilité en sédiment grande.
                \item de la croissance sous un vent unidirectionnel.
            \end{itemize}
           \\
            Objectifs & Étude de l'orientation longitudinale :
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt, label=\textbullet, parsep=0pt, after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip} ]
                \item Développement d'un formalisme sous des vents multidirectionnels.
                \item Etude des dunes longitudinales dans le cas d'une faible disponibilité en sédiment. (\emph{Fingering mode})
                \item Inversion: données topographiques $\longrightarrow$ Données de vents $\rightarrow$ paléo-climats.
            \end{itemize} \\
            Outils & Modèle numérique (Rescal), Données expérimentales, Théorie. \\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]