# Remove space below enumitem inside tabularx

Tags: spacing, tabularx, enumitem

I'm using a list from enumitem-package inside table from tabularx-package. Between the table-row, which contains the list, and and the next table-row there is a space I would like to avoid. How do I do that? This is some basic example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx} % featured tables

\usepackage{enumitem} % control layout of itemize, enumerate, description
\setlist{nosep}
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=\dimexpr 1em}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} % table spacing

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{4cm}X}
  lorem ipsum a & lorem ipsum b
  \begin{itemize}[label=--]
    \item lorem ipsum c
    \item lorem ipsum d
  \end{itemize}\\
  lorem ipsum e & lorem ipsum f\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: preview of code example]

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368523/empty-line-in-tabular-after-enumerate-itemize , too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a negative `\vspace` to the list options:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx} % featured tables

\usepackage{enumitem} % control layout of itemize, enumerate, description
\setlist{nosep}
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=1em}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1} % table spacing

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{4cm}X}
  lorem ipsum a 
  & lorem ipsum b
  \begin{itemize}[label=--,after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
    \item lorem ipsum c
    \item lorem ipsum d
  \end{itemize} \\
  lorem ipsum e 
  & lorem ipsum f\\
  lorem ipsum g &
  lorem ipsum h
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: In fact, using `after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip}` as described in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372156/111808) answer has better spacing.

Comment: @MekeorMelire Sorry, the `\arraystretch` was a mistake. But the `\dimexpr` is not required.